# control posts order by select option

Tags: theme-development, loop, pagination

I have created a custom `category.php` file and it works fine and i am using a select option section to allow users to sort posts and it is also sorting but the problem is when i navigate to another post's page the order returns back to the default, i want to retain the user's selection, so should i use cookies or there is another best practice?

Here is the file's code:

```
                    <?php
                get_header();?>
                <div id="Content">
                    <div class="content_wrapper clearfix">
                        <div class="sections_group">
                            <div class="section">
                                <div class="section_wrapper clearfix">
                                    <?php
                                        $this_category = get_category($cat);

                                        $cats=get_categories(array('hide_empty' => '0', 'parent'=>$this_category ->cat_ID,'order'=> 'ASC','depth'=> '1'));

                                        foreach ($cats as $cat) {;
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="one-third column fltr">
                                        <div class="crs-wrap">
                                            <div class="circle_img scale-with-grid wp-post-image hover-mask">
                                                <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>" class="">
                                                <img class="wp-post-image" src= "<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" ></img>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="crsbtn">
                                                <a class="button" href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id);?>"target="_self"><?php echo $cat->cat_name ;?></a>
                                                <p style="color:white"> عدد الموضوعات&nbsp;<?php echo ipt_kb_total_cat_post_count($cat->term_id);?></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php };?>
                                    <?php
                                    $r=$_POST['orderby'];
                                        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                                        $newargs = array(
                                            'order'    => $r,
                                            'paged' => $paged,
                                            'nopaging' => false,
                                            'tax_query' => array(
                                                array(
                                                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                                    'field' => 'name',
                                                    'terms' => $this_category->cat_name,
                                                    'include_children' => 0
                                                )
                                            )
                                        );
                                        $nopostsparent= new wp_query( $newargs );
                                         if ($nopostsparent->have_posts()) {
                                                echo '<div class="posts_wrapper clearfix">';
                                                    while ($nopostsparent->have_posts() ){
                                                        $nopostsparent->the_post();
                                                        get_template_part( 'includes/content', get_post_type() );
                                                    }
                                                echo '</div>';

                                        // pagination
                                        if(function_exists( 'rc_pagination' )):
                                            rc_pagination();
                                        else:
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link(__('&larr; Newer Entries', 'brandon')) ?></div>
                                        <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Older Entries &rarr;', 'brandon')) ?></div>
                                    <?php  endif;}?>

                                </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php if ($nopostsparent->have_posts()) {
                            echo '<div id="catleft" class="column">
                                    <h2 class="prosentra_text_r"><i class="fa fa-smile-o"style="padding-left:5px;"></i>لسه جديد فى الشغلانة !</h2>
                                    <p class="prosentra_text_r">إذا كانت هذه هى بدايتك مع هذا القسم يمكنك عرض الموضوعات من بدايتها</p>
                                     <form id ="orderby" action="" method="post" class="prosentra_text_r">
                                            <select name="orderby" style="float:right;">
                                            <option selected="true" style="display:none;"><strong>حدد طريقة العرض</strong></option>
                                                <option value="ASC"><strong>ترتيب المقالات من البداية</strong></option>
                                                <option value="DESC"><strong>ترتيب المقالات من النهاية</strong></option>
                                            </select>
                                            <input type="submit" value="ترتيب" />
                                    </form>
                                </div>';
                            }?>
                            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You could either use cookies, or else set a query string on every URL you link to. I'd lean toward cookies since editing the links may be a pain and it would retain the preference even if they leave the site, whereas if you use query strings they could come back and access the categories with no query string and have to reset again.

Comment: thank for your support, i have made it using cookies and it is working, but i was seeking a better approach

Comment: I think the opposite to @WebElaine; I would use links or URL params since cookies or session variables makes your pages impossible to cache as statics files, something very important for performance (for exmaple with wp supe cache or other similar plugins).

Comment: @cybmeta thank you, but how to use url to get this done because I have no control on urls and may be there is but I don't know how